# Stack Postfix Notation evaluation equals different to what infix calc gets

Tags: c++, flex-lexer

I was working on a simple 1 file language with Flex and I came across an issue.

The infix calculator expression is: `1 + 2 * 5 -32`, which on a calculator equals `-21`.

My postfix calculator expression is: `1 2 5 32 - * +`, which with my calculator equals `55`.

Here is my Flex code:

```
%{
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

stack<int> numberStack;
int a;
int b;

extern "C" int yywrap() { }
%}

%%

[ \t\n] ;
[0-9]+  numberStack.push(atoi(yytext));
"+" a = numberStack.top(); numberStack.pop(); b = numberStack.top(); numberStack.pop(); numberStack.push(a+b);
"-" a = numberStack.top(); numberStack.pop(); b = numberStack.top(); numberStack.pop(); numberStack.push(a-b);
"*" a = numberStack.top(); numberStack.pop(); b = numberStack.top(); numberStack.pop(); numberStack.push(a*b);
"/" a = numberStack.top(); numberStack.pop(); b = numberStack.top(); numberStack.pop(); numberStack.push(a/b);

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    yylex();
    fclose(yyin);
    cout << numberStack.top() << endl;
    numberStack.pop();
    return 0;
}
```

Please excuse my way of doing things (especially the copy pasted C code as I am a bit rusty in Flex), I just saw a video on Polish Reverse notation and its reference to stacks, so I want to make a scripting language that uses it and it took me approximately 5 minutes to make.

I already know that I can't do division (but I left it in) because it will most-likely return floats which will be displayed as a 0 because of the stack is of type `int`.

Can anyone explain why my Polish Reverse Notation calculator scripting languge evalutes `1 2 5 32 - * +` to `55`, not the correct answer `-21`?

Comment: You should step through your code using a debugger. Inspect the variables values and see how it differs from the result you want.

Comment: you have just discovered why RPN exists. Its is explicit about operator binding and order, whereas calculators need ( and ) to 'do the right thing'. If you do 1 + 2 *(32 - 5) in your calculator it will agree

Comment: In C, dividing two `int`s returns an `int`. If you wanted to work with floating point numbers, use a stack of `double`s (and fix the number pattern to recognise numbers with decimal points.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (almost) nothing wrong with the result of your code.

The correct translation of `1 + 2 * 5 - 32` (according to usual rules of operator precedence) to RPN is: `1 2 5 * + 32 -`. RPN `1 2 5 32 - * +` is the translation of `1 + 2 * (5 - 32)`

The one problem with your code is that you are computing the reverse of the correct functions. That is, `5 32 -` is returning 27 rather than -27 (and `32 5 -` is computing -27 rather than 27). A similar problem will be visible with `/`. (Since `+` and `*` are commutative, the problem goes unnoticed).

So in all of the actions, `a` and `b` should be reversed.

There is also no need to use global variables `a` and `b`:

```
"-"   { int right = numberStack.top();
        numberStack.pop();
        int left = numberStack.top();
        numberStack.pop();
        numberStack.push(left - right);
      }
```

Obviously, it would be better to check that the stack is not empty before calling `.top()`.